# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto ao chamar classe de dll

Tags: c#

Estou tentando chamar uma função de uma classe que está em uma DLL. Mas o erro "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto" está aparecendo, não entendo por que pois na IDE não mostra nenhum erro.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Segue código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace player
{
    public partial class frmPrincipal : Form
    {

        System.Media.SoundPlayer soundPlayer;
        RSPOggPlayer279a.RSPOggPlayClass playerRSP;

        public frmPrincipal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void tocar()
        {

            playerRSP.UseEncryption(true, "988d90fsdhfnu943yrtherjh0qw9rifj");
            //playerRSP.PlayFile("C:\Users\kleber.santos\7b.ogg");





            //byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\kleber.santos\Downloads\africa-toto.wav");
            //System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Users\kleber.santos\Downloads\africa-toto.wav");
            //var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, true);
            //soundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(memoryStream);
            //Play();
        }

        public void Play()
        {
            soundPlayer.Play();
        }

        private void BtnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tocar();
        }

        private void BtnVolume_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: É algum objeto que esqueceu de instanciar, em qual linha o erro ocorre?

Comment: na linha 36 ->  playerRSP.UseEncryption(true, "988d90fsdhfnu943yrtherjh0qw9rifj");, no debug ele diz que playerRSP é null.

Answer (score 0):

Kleber,
Essa mensagem é típica para objetos não instanciados.
Verifica a instância do objeto RSPOggPlayer279a.RSPOggPlayClass.
Acredito que é uma classe criada por você.

Comment: é uma classe de uma OCX, quando eu tento instanciar da que "RSPOggPlayClass" não contém um construtor que aceita 0 argumentos.

Estou fazendo assim:

playerRSP = new RSPOggPlayer279a.RSPOggPlayClass();
playerRSP.UseEncryption(true, "988d90fsdhfnu943yrtherjh0qw9rifj");

Comment: Verifica se não possui outros construtores, com parâmetros, ou um método GetInstance()

Comment: Tem outras funções mas também não respondem, não tem me GetInstance(), pois a OCX é antiga de 2005. No VB 5 é so chamar dessa forma ai e funciona.

Comment: São paradigmas diferentes.
Eu costumo escrever o tipo, nesse caso RSPOggPlayClass, parenteses, virgula dentro dos parenteses e clicar seta para cima e para baixo